# How to assign Single cell to range?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim TxtRng As Range
    Set TxtRng = ActiveCell

    If Not Intersect(Target, TxtRng) Is Nothing Then

------------Statements           

    End If

End Sub
```

i am getting an infinite loop. I just want to assign a single cell address to the range (eg. "B6" or "A5", as per selection)

Answer (score 1):

Just set it to the Target:

```
Set TxtRang = Target
```

Then you're golden.

Cheers, LC